# Access facebook using react native

Tags: react-native

I am using fbsdk in react native . I am able to get the facebook login page. But i want that when i click on login , then it sholud fetch the details such as Age, Firstname, gender from facebook and display it .

This is the code for facebook login.

App.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { View } from 'react-native';
 import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

 export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <LoginButton
      onLoginFinished={
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            console.log("login is cancelled.");
          } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
              (data) => {
                console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
      onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
     </View>
   );
  }
});
```

What all i need to add in this code , in order to fetch the details from facebook and display it.

Comment: Well, this is the exact same example code of that library. What else have you tried to get these values? does the library let you do it? are you getting an error?

Comment: No i am not getting any error. I am getting facebook login page. But i want when click on login, details from facebook (age,gender) should get fetched and shown on screen.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am getting no idea , how to proceed further. I had just started learning react native from yesterday.

Comment: have you tried following fbsdk documentation and examples?

Comment: you have only started react native yesterday, but you know javascript right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `LoginManager` from `react-native-fbsdk`, and use the following code on the onclick function

```
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["details_you_need_from_logged_in_profile"]).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log("Login was Cancelled");
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Login was a Success" + result.grantedPermissions.toString()
      );
    }
  },
```